# Control the Transform component of an object while the animation is playing

Tags: unity, animation, mecanim

It seems the the animation controls the Transform component of the gameobject, hence making it not possible to control the transform properties while the animation is playing. Is there any way to control the Transform component of an object while the animation is playing, like rotating it for example?

Comment: You could wrap it into a parent gameobject and instead transform that..